# Apache2 - Document root where you start Apache in CLI (windows)

Tags: apache, apache2

Is it possible to set the Document Root of apache where you start apache. Just like you have with the build in PHP server, you start it in a certain folder and it uses that as Document Root. Is that possible to do in Apache too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any option to do this so I just created this simple batch script what works fine for me:

```
@Echo off
powershell -Command "(gc C:\Apache24\conf\original\httpd.conf) -replace 'c:/Apache24/htdocs', '%cd%' | Out-File C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf" -Encoding Ascii
Echo Started Apache2 on: %cd%
httpd
pause
```

Comment: you can also use "-c" arg to httpd.exe to add a DocumentRoot directive at the end of the real config,  although it wouldn't work for  vhosts.